# write the files in root directory in jailbreak phone,permitted?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, jailbreak

my phone was jailbreak,I want to write the files in `/var/mobile/Documents/`, I using the `NSFileManager` to working,but it cant working, I print the `error` log was "The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation not permitted", ok,I think `NSFileManager` just can using in `sandbox` maybe that I using the C(fread and fwrite), but also the file just can read,cant write,how to fix it,I just want write the file to the outside of the `sandbox` directory in my app?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing with the default C standard IO method? This has worked perfectly for me in the past:

```
FILE *file = fopen("/debugging_private_data.txt", "w");
if(!file){
    // log an error opening file
} else {
    fprintf(file, "My value: %d\n", x);
    fclose(file);
}
```

This creates the file debugging_private_data.txt at the `root` directory. If you can write there (have root permission), you can write anywhere I guess.