# Pass data between apps - Jailbroken iOS app development

Tags: ios, sandbox, jailbreak, file-access, logos

I am trying to make a Jailbroken iOS tweak and had a question. I need to send some data between apps. I took the approach of just saving the data(a simple string) to a file and then accessing it from the other app since my device is jailbroken, however I can't figure out how to do this. Because of sand-boxing problems, simply calling [NSString writeToFile:] doesn't work if you are trying to write data outside your apps directory. I have also tried using C to write to a file outside my apps directory, using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20113402/write-the-files-in-root-directory-in-jailbreak-phone-permitted) SO answer as a guide, but that didn't work either. How can I save a file outside my apps directory? I'm also open to alternative ways of transferring data between apps if it works properly. Also, I'm testing this on an iPhone5 and ios 7.0.4.

Thanks!

EDIT:
If I use this code:

```
%hook TKToneTableController
- (void)tableView:(id)arg1 didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(id)arg2{

    //int section = [arg2 section];
    //int row = [arg2 row];

    NSError *error;
    [@"TESTTEXT" writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/test.txt",kBundlePath,nil] atomically:true encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

    UIAlertView *testAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Yo!" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",error,nil] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [testAlert show];
    %orig(arg1, arg2);
}
%end
```

It does not work and I see this error message:
[image]

I have also tried this code for saving a string:

```
FILE *file = fopen("/debugging_private_data.txt", "w");
if(!file){
    // log an error opening file
} else {
    fprintf(file, "TEST");
    fclose(file);
}
```

but it doesn't work either. I have also tried using the above C code to save to the directory `/Library/Application Support/` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: We need to see the code you have tried. Also the directories you tried to write to.

Comment: How much data are you sending?  Is this simple string just for test purposes, or are you really only wanting to share a few bytes of data between apps?

Comment: I just want to pass a simple string for test purposes. In future posts I will either type in the error messages or scale down the screenshots. Sorry!

Comment: I understand that you are passing a string for test purposes, but for your real app, what kind of data are you passing?  Large amounts?  Dictionaries?  Please tell us what kind of data you're passing.  That makes it easier for an answerer to give you a good recommendation, and a specific example.  Thanks.

Comment: Dictionaries mostly... Any ideas as to how to do this?